# Normalize JSON API data to columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, hubspot

I'm trying to get data from our Hubspot CRM database and convert it to a dataframe using pandas. I'm still a beginner in python, but I can't get json_normalize to work.

The output from the database is i JSON format like this:

```
{'archived': False,
 'archived_at': None,
 'associations': None,
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 21, 17, 56, 24, 739000, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'id': 'xxx',
 'properties': {'createdate': '2019-12-21T17:56:24.739Z',
                'email': 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com',
                'firstname': 'John',
                'hs_object_id': 'xxx',
                'lastmodifieddate': '2020-04-22T04:37:40.274Z',
                'lastname': 'Hansen'},
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 4, 37, 40, 274000, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'archived': False,
 'archived_at': None,
 'associations': None,
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 21, 17, 52, 38, 485000, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'id': 'bbb',
 'properties': {'createdate': '2019-12-21T17:52:38.485Z',
                'email': 'bbb@bbb.dk',
                'firstname': 'John2',
                'hs_object_id': 'bbb',
                'lastmodifieddate': '2020-05-19T07:18:28.384Z',
                'lastname': 'Hansen2'},
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19, 7, 18, 28, 384000, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'archived': False,
 'archived_at': None,
 'associations': None,
```

etc.
Trying to put it into a dataframe using this code:

```
import hubspot
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os

client = hubspot.Client.create(api_key='################')

all_contacts = contacts_client = client.crm.contacts.get_all()

df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(all_contacts,'properties')
df.head

df.to_csv ('All contacts.csv')
```

But i keep getting an error that i can't resolve.

I have also tried the

```
pd.dataframe(all_contacts)
```

and

```
pf.dataframe.from_dict(all_contacts)
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is your desired dataframe format?

Comment: Oh yeah of course.
I want to get a dataframe by columns on the "properties" tag
Email,                        Firstname,      hs_object_id,      lastname
xxxxx@xxxxx.com,    John,              xxx,                   Hansen,
etc. with all the contacts. I have around 2,500

The error i'm getting is "AttributeError: 'SimplePublicObject' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: Is the output from the database exactly what you have pasted? It looks like it should be contained in a tuple since you have multiple elements with the same "key" values but different data (e.g. archived" or "archived_at").

Comment: Yes it is the exact output from the database, only anonymized and with 2500 datapoints. 

Any idea on to turn it in to columns based on the properties field?

Comment: I think I have a solution but before I post (an potentially unhelpful answer), can you tell me what `print(type(all_contacts))` returns, please.

Comment: Great! It returns <class 'list'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all_contacts variable is a list of dictionary-like elements. So to create the dataframe I have used list comprehension to create a tuple that only contains the 'properties' for each dictionary-like element.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

data = ({'archived': False,
         'archived_at': None,
         'associations': None,
         'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 21, 17, 56, 24, 739000, tzinfo=tzutc()),
         'id': 'xxx',
         'properties': {'createdate': '2019-12-21T17:56:24.739Z',
                        'email': 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com',
                        'firstname': 'John',
                        'hs_object_id': 'xxx',
                        'lastmodifieddate': '2020-04-22T04:37:40.274Z',
                        'lastname': 'Hansen'},
         'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 4, 37, 40, 274000, tzinfo=tzutc())},
        {'archived': False,
         'archived_at': None,
         'associations': None,
         'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 21, 17, 52, 38, 485000, tzinfo=tzutc()),
         'id': 'bbb',
         'properties': {
             'createdate': '2019-12-21T17:52:38.485Z',
             'email': 'bbb@bbb.dk',
             'firstname': 'John2',
             'hs_object_id': 'bbb',
             'lastmodifieddate': '2020-05-19T07:18:28.384Z',
             'lastname': 'Hansen2'},
         'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19, 7, 18, 28, 384000, tzinfo=tzutc())})
df = pd.DataFrame([row['properties'] for row in data])
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                 createdate            email  ...          lastmodifieddate lastname
0  2019-12-21T17:56:24.739Z  xxxxx@xxxxx.com  ...  2020-04-22T04:37:40.274Z   Hansen
1  2019-12-21T17:52:38.485Z       bbb@bbb.dk  ...  2020-05-19T07:18:28.384Z  Hansen2

[2 rows x 6 columns]
```